# svg, keep text from upside down

Tags: svg

I have a path in svg, it's original point is on the right, the following points are on the left, then I add a textPath to svg, all text are upside down.
How can I keep the text upright and always show from left to right?
This cost me a lot of time!
I'll appreciate your answer!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    </style>
    <script>
    function CreateSVG(points, container) {

      var id = "idSVG";
      var ns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
      var xlinkns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
      var lineWidth = 10;
      var color = "rgba(120,120,120,0.7)";
      var path = document.createElementNS(ns, "path");
      path.setAttribute('stroke-linecap', 'round');
      path.setAttribute('stroke-linejoin', 'round');
      path.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', 'solid');
      path.setAttribute('fill', 'none');
      path.setAttribute('id', id);
      var _canvas = document.createElementNS(ns, 'svg');
      _canvas.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns:xlink', xlinkns);
      _canvas.setAttribute('pointer-events', 'none');
      //this._canvas.appendChild(this.path);
      var defs = document.createElementNS(ns, "defs");
      defs.appendChild(path);
      var useSvg = document.createElementNS(ns, 'use');
      useSvg.setAttributeNS(xlinkns, 'xlink:href', '#' + id);
      useSvg.setAttribute('fill', 'none');
      useSvg.setAttribute('stroke', 'red');
      var textSvg = document.createElementNS(ns, 'text');
      var textPathSvg = document.createElementNS(ns, 'textPath');
      textPathSvg.setAttributeNS(xlinkns, 'xlink:href', '#' + id);
      textPathSvg.appendChild(document.createTextNode('test text'));
      textSvg.appendChild(textPathSvg);

      _canvas.appendChild(defs);
      _canvas.appendChild(useSvg);
      _canvas.appendChild(textSvg);

      var minX, maxX, minY, maxY, x, y, width, height;
      for(var i = 0, len = points.length; i < len; i++) {
        x = points[i].x;
        y = points[i].y;
        if(minX == undefined || minX > x) {
          minX = x;
        }
        if(maxX == undefined || maxX < x) {
          maxX = x;
        }
        if(minY == undefined || minY > y) {
          minY = y;
        }
        if(maxY == undefined || maxY < y) {
          maxY = y;
        }
      }
      minX = minX - lineWidth;
      minY = minY - lineWidth;
      width = maxX - minX + lineWidth;
      height = maxY - minY + lineWidth;

      _canvas.setAttribute('style', 'position:absolute;');
      _canvas.setAttribute('width', width);
      _canvas.setAttribute('height', height);
      _canvas.setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 ' + width + ' ' + height);
      _canvas.setAttribute('stroke', 'true');
      path.setAttribute('stroke-width', lineWidth);
      path.setAttribute('stroke', color);
      var d = [];
      for(var i = 0, len = points.length; i < len; i++) {
        d[i] = (points[i].x - minX + lineWidth / 2) + ',' + (points[i].y - minY + lineWidth / 2);
      }
      path.setAttribute('d', 'M' + d.join(' '));
      container.appendChild(_canvas);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="CreateSVG([{x:200, y:200}, {x:40, y:60}], document.getElementById('svgContainer'))">
    <div id="svgContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Comment: Don't need code, examples about "textPath" in web are all origin point is on the left, the text will be certainly right side up, but if the origin point is on the right, all other points are on the left, it's just like a line rotate 180 degrees, all text are upside down.

Comment: Add *your* code, it makes it easier to play with. Did you try to generate your path the other way around ? Or maybe `direction="rtl"` ?

Comment: If it cost you a lot of time imagine how much it would cost us to try to solve your issues *without any code*.

Comment: I have submit my code, sorry for my rudeness.